# Wicket.Event.add() is undefined

Tags: wicket, wicket-7, wicket-8

While migrating from Wicket 7 to Wicket 8, following official guidelines and fixing all compiling issues, as well as all the test that are failing, there was an interesting removal that was not documented anywhere.

`

```
JavaScriptResourceReference wicketEvent = (JavaScriptResourceReference) getJavaScriptLibrarySettings().getWicketEventReference();
```

`

When running the application we have to check whether any of the new changes affect use cases, I found out that multiple parts are not loading due to this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aBlf.png)

Which points to this snippet of code which I assume is from the framework:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npjDA.png)

I have tried searching for this on multiple platforms but it is not documented at all.
I hope I am not on a wrong track.

```
getJavaScriptLibrarySettings().setJQueryReference(JQueryResourceReference.getV2());
        JavaScriptResourceReference ajaxJquery = (JavaScriptResourceReference) getJavaScriptLibrarySettings().getWicketAjaxReference();
        JavaScriptResourceReference scrolling = new JavaScriptResourceReference(ScrollingResourceReference.class, "scrolling.js");

        getResourceBundles().addJavaScriptBundle(EcareReference.class, "ecare-wicket.js", ajaxJquery, scrolling,
                new LazyLoadingResourceReference());
```

Here is the context in which I use that snippet.

Answer (score 0):

wicket-event.js has been merged to wicket-ajax.js!

I guess you need to replace `Event` with `Ajax` in:

```
JavaScriptResourceReference wicketEvent = (JavaScriptResourceReference) getJavaScriptLibrarySettings().getWicketEventReference();
```

but it is not clear how exactly you use it from that single line.

Wicket Ajax behaviors should contribute WicketAjaxReference by default, so the JavaScript problems might be caused by something else.

**Update**:
Try to change the order of the bundle items. Currently it is:

```
 EcareReference.class, "ecare-wicket.js", ajaxJquery, ...
```

Most probably the bug is that `ecare-wicket.js` depends on wicket-ajax.js, so their order should be:

```
 EcareReference.class, ajaxJquery, "ecare-wicket.js", ...
```

Comment: I have added the context for the snippet.
Do you have any other idea what else might cause such an error ?
The application did not have this issue before the upgrade.
All the unit tests are green after modifying the new changes from Wicket8, according to their guide on the update...

Comment: The unit tests check the Java behavior, not the JavaScript. They might check that some JS string is constructed but they will not execute it!